# Are elastic collisions possible ever in real life?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

I encountered a question that entails a bullet being shot at a pendulum sand bag that causes it to swing. One part of the question asks if the collision is elastic or inelastic. Would I say its inelastic since realistically energy would be lost even though I used the conservation of momentum and energy formulas to get my answer?

Comment: First, the question in the title and the question in the body are different questions. Which one do you actually want an answer to? Second, I think that saying "it has to be inelastic because no collision is exactly elastic" is a cop-out. There is a much better answer to this question that I think it would benefit you a lot to try to figure out. Trying to find answers to questions like this is part of the learning process, and I don't think it would benefit you for us to just hand you the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collision is inelastic. Not because of non-idealities imposed by the real world, but because even on paper the collision is inelastic. If the problem is what I am imagining, after the collision the bullet is lodged in the sand. Any time two colliding objects stick together, (mechanical) energy is not conserved.

The solution to this problem indeed involves "conservation of energy and momentum," but it's a two-step process. Step 1: Use conservation of momentum to determine the velocity of the bag immediately after the collision. Step 2: Use conservation of energy to determine how high the bag swings. Notably, you don't use conservation of mechanical energy during the collision, *because that energy is not conserved*.

Comment: Total energy is conserved for an inelastic collision, kinetic energy is not.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I'm only in Grade 12 physics so I was wondering if we should just ignore real world conditions and just assume that energy is perfectly conserved.

Comment: @JohnDarby (lightly) edited, thanks

Comment: @JohnDarby unless of course  there's a chemical change.  Such a change will lead to a change in total mass of the system, so energy is not conserved.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft I assumed this is a classical mechanics question.  For either a chemical or nuclear reaction, considering the change in (rest) mass as energy (products to reactants, can be + or -) the total energy is conserved.  Of course, the change in mass is much less for chemical than nuclear reactions.

Answer (score 0):

In many problems in mechanics, bodies are considered rigid bodies and as such can have no change in internal energy.  Examples include rigid bodies sliding with slipping down an incline, and elastic collisions between two rigid bodies.

In reality, no body is rigid but for certain situations this is a reasonable assumption.

Regarding your bullet/sand bag question, I suggest considering qualitatively the heating effects in real life.  As @Jahan Claes states, the conservation of momentum holds for an inelastic collision.  The conservation of **kinetic energy** does not hold for an inelastic collision; the conservation of total energy does hold but that requires evaluating changes in internal energy (heating effects) which I believe is outside the scope of the problem.  The solution provided by @Jahan Claes is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

All quantum interactions are elastic, since  things like electrons and protons can't "deform."  Unless you want to claim that tertiary particles constitute an inelastic effect, that is.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Elastic collisions never happen classically, as things such as friction and air resistance factor into the entire system. However, it can be near-elastic.